# Material UI monthpicker not showing proper UI

Tags: css, datepicker, material-ui

While adding the following code,

```html
<MonthPicker/>
```

I am not getting a proper UI for the month picker, this happens on the website as well at times.

[image]

I see that month picker is being used differently

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved - delete the yarn lock and reinstall using latest material-ui and datefns libraries